# The remote copy of database "<DBNAME>" is not related to the local copy of the database

Tags: sql-server-2012, high-availability

I'm trying to join a secondary DB to my SQL Server 2012 Availability Group following this article:

[Join a Secondary Database to an Availability Group (SQL Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878535.aspx)

When I attempt this the local SQL server windows event log gives error 1407:

```
The remote copy of database "<DBNAME>" is not related to the local copy of the database
```

I have followed all the steps and created a recent backup and restore with NORECOVERY.

The error log of the destination SQL server gives these errors:

```
AlwaysOn: The local replica of availability group '<AGNAME>' is going offline because the corresponding resource in the Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC) cluster is no longer online. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

The state of the local availability replica in availability group '<AGNAME>' has changed from 'SECONDARY_NORMAL' to 'RESOLVING_NORMAL'. The replica state changed because of either a startup, a failover, a communication issue, or a cluster error. For more information, see the availability group dashboard, SQL Server error log, Windows Server Failover Cluster management console or Windows Server Failover Cluster log. 

The state of the local availability replica in availability group '<AGNAME>' has changed from 'RESOLVING_NORMAL' to 'NOT_AVAILABLE'. The replica state changed because of either a startup, a failover, a communication issue, or a cluster error. For more information, see the availability group dashboard, SQL Server error log, Windows Server Failover Cluster management console or Windows Server Failover Cluster log.
```

The cluster and all its nodes are online. The AG dashboard does not give any additional information to help diagnose the problem.

Opening all firewalls did not solve the issue.

The Windows Event log gives this line:

```
The database 'DelphiOBUDB' is marked RESTORING and is in a state that does not allow recovery to be run.
```

However, the DB is left in Restoring mode when you restore it and specify the NORECOVERY flag as per the tutorial guidelines.

How can I join the DB to my availability group?

Comment: This question may be better asked at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Although deleting the backup history looked promising, it did not help. http://blogs.technet.com/b/sql_server_isv/archive/2010/10/26/how-to-clean-up-old-database-backup-history.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The problem was something to do with deleting the database prior to re-running the powershell scripts to re-create the availability group.

I also saw this error when attempting to use the same DB name:

```
Add-SqlAvailabilityDatabase : The connection to the primary replica is not active.  The command cannot be processed.
```

The answer was to execute the powershell scripts to create the database and availability group using a NEW and DIFFERENT database name.